# What did The Joker eat at the Harvey Dent fundraiser?

Tags: dc, batman, nolan-batman-trilogy, the-dark-knight

When The Joker crashes the party, he grabs a skewer containing a shrimp and a small red object, and eats the red thing.  What is it?

The shot happens at about 1:30 in the clip below:

[image]

Comment: A piece of melon?

Comment: @Richard Possible.  More likely than a flower.  :)

Comment: It is poorly cut, which is surprising, considering how much money Bruce Wayne would have spent on the catering.

Comment: I'd put money on a tomato

Comment: @Kevin - [I'd put a tomato on money](http://eatdrinkbetter.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Tomato-on-Dollar-Bill.jpg)

Comment: @Kevin It's half a cherry tomato, I reckon.

Comment: @Kevin - But the money would get wet and the tomato would taste awful if you did that.

Comment: What's with the downvotes?  Don't you people care about nutrition?

Comment: @WadCheber - For triviality, I'd guess.

Comment: @Richard - Getting all the essential vitamins and minerals on a daily basis is *hardly* trivial.

Comment: Haha I like your 'out-of-the-norm' questions. +1. Also thanks for reminding me to get some fruit from the shops :)

Comment: I don't get the downvotes...so have a +1 for reminding me that kebabs exist.

Comment: @WadCheberstandswithMonica: yeah, what's with the downvotes? why so serious??

Comment: What did The Joker eat at the Harvey Dent fundraiser? Anything he jolly well wanted, until Batman showed up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Given its bright red color, the object in question would appear to be a slice of tomato.**

[**Kebabs**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kebab), or skewers, is a common appetizer served at [cocktail parties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocktail_party) like the Wayne fundraiser. And two of the most common foods to include on a shrimp kebab are [melon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melon) and [tomato](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomato), both of which enhance the flavor of the meat. The object in question appears too red to be [watermelon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watermelon), which would be a more pinkish color. It's also too large to be a [cherry tomato](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherry_tomato), which is common. Therefore, the object is most likely a normal tomato, sliced into wedges like so:

[image]

Comment: I'm a chef, and if my tomato wedges looked like that, they'd be thrown out and my knife skills would be sharply criticized by my boss. Especially if I was preparing food for a billionaire's fundraiser.

Comment: I often cook kebabs, but I don't use tomatoes or shrimp. My wife does, but she prefers whole cherry tomatoes with her shrimp. I make MY kebabs using beef or pork chunks with cantaloupe and honeydew. The picture was just the closest thing I could find to what we see on-screen.

Comment: No, I mean the tomato in the movie was poorly cut.  The one in your picture is okay.

Comment: @WadCheber ah, gotcha. Based on the shot you have above, it looks like maybe a small tomato cut in half. Dunno - only way I like tomato is in sauce form or diced up in something else.

Answer (score 2):

The script and novelisation merely identify it as "*food*".

> > ***Tables of food and decorations
> >     fill the hall.*** Alfred is talking to Rachel at the front door.

and

> At ten minutes after nine that night, Harvey Dent and Rachel Dawes got
>   out of an elevator. Dent stopped, scanning the area in front of him, a
>   lavish room almost as big as a basketball court filled with dozens of
>   people, each wearing thousands of dollars worth of clothing and
>   jewelry. **Tuxedoed waiters circulated through the crowd offering food
>   and drink from silver trays.**

Answer (score -4):

It's a rose. You should watch the clip again. The Joker proceeded towards a flower bouquet and picked a rose. Small and weird details like this made Heath Ledger the Joker at his very best.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! Can you provide a screenshot of the Joker picking a flower from the bouquet? Watching the clip again isn't always possible (in this case, the one linked in the question has been removed from YouTube).